# Is there any limit of size for a drawable in an Android ImageView?

Tags: android, android-widget

In my app widget I'm simply trying to show an ImageView with a src taken from a drawable, I don't think it's too complicated:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/large_cover"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_widget_placeholder_big"/>
```

This image `ic_widget_placeholder_big` doesn't show, the widget is just blank. The interesting thing is that if I use another image it does show. I even tried with a larger image. I don't get it because I think it's an issue with the size of the image. I tried to use the hdpi asset for my xhdpi phone and the image showed (pixelated of course).

So I was wondering if there's a limit in terms of size of image for an ImageView source?

This image is of 384 × 384 in xhdpi and weights 123 KB

Oh and I haven't found anything interesting in the logs.

UPDATE:

I've just tried using that drawable in an ImageView inside the app and it doesn't even show. Hmm I don't get it.

Comment: try and set your scale type to fitXY then you might be able to actually see an image

Comment: nope it doesn't show. I think it's more related to the drawable not being loaded. The interesting thing is that the space takes the correct size. The widget is actually 100dpx100dp

Comment: Occassionally I had come across what I thought was the image being put into my workspace correctly. But occassionally in Eclipse I copied the drawable/image as a link only.  Not an actual copy.  And this resolved in either the image not showing or some sort of error, I don't recall.  Just shooting from memory here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what the issue was. I had one asset per density and the one from the xhdpi folder was not correctly exported (damn you designer ;) ). It was either in another format or the color profile was wrong. Which ended up with a image not showing. Luckily I had a xhdpi device with me!